# How do I get wifi working on hp stream x360

Tags: wireless, hp, stream

My laptop (HP Stream x360) was working terrible on Windows 8 so I've installed Ubuntu. But now I don have a wireless connection. Can anyone help me getting wifi to work? I've read solutions for the stream 11, but that doesn't same the solution for the x360

Thanks in advance.
Miguel

The output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I've just updated question with terminal output

Comment: I actually have the exact same network controller as you do! Try going to the Dash (press Windows key), type "System Settings", and click "Driver Manager". Ubuntu will refresh itself on what additional software your computer may need to function properly. However, if you receive a warning about you needing an internet connection, then you will temporarily need to use an Ethernet cable to connect your computer to the internet; and after, click "OK" on the warning. Ubuntu will then perform the refresh. You should now see options for wifi drivers; click the recommended one and then "apply"

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy to see that someone with the same network controller has working wifi. I've tried to follow your instructions, but somehow there is no "driver manager" in the "system settings".  The only window I've found is "software & update" --> "Additional Drivers". In this window I've checked "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA Wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)". However this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI (aka BIOS) settings, and Wi-Fi will work.

Secure Boot does not allow to load the unsigned proprietary driver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: Wifi is working now!!! I've spend hours and hours, tried several commands in the terminal: wouldn't expect such a simple solution: thnks!

Comment: There is a manual for Broadcom wireless adapters http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/167850. Now there is information about Secure Boot too.

Comment: @Pilot6: You're showing up in the LQ review queue. ;-P

Comment: @DavidFoerster I know. It is because the answer is short. But this question will be asked many times. It makes sense to have one and mark others as duplicates. The Broadcom manual is too long now to find this simple solution.

Comment: @Pilot6: I agree. I just wanted to point that fact out to you.